# what is the exact time to add food color in sweet rice?

Tags: rice, color

I always confused to add the color in sweet rice .what is the exact time to add food color .As i add color when the rice is boiled. is it right?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not perfect time to add color after boiling the rice.

After boiling the rice you should add sugar and other ingredients of your choice and than at the time of steaming stage you should add color in your rice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make single color sweet rice then you will add the color in the water before putting rice in hot(boiled) water and when the color is completely mixed then you should add the rice in water.

But if you want to add more(you can say more than one) color in sweet rice then you should mix a single color in a 2 tea spoon milk. Do for all color the same thing and after the rice boiled and you added these rice in oil mix with your selected dry fruit and at the time when you leave these rice for 10 to 15 minute on slow heat at that time you should make little hole in rice with the help of any stick and then put the colored milk and then leave it for 10 to 15 minute and after 15 minutes your sweet dish is ready with multiple beautiful color combination.

I also tried it for many time and every time i got a beautiful colored rice dish.